# How to create alert on metric insights using the dataset that I would Provide in the description below

Tags: dataset, metrics, connector

Lets understand the problem first. This is the given csv file that I have created.

[image]

Now I want this dataset to load into Metric insights dashboard and I do not know how to do it.

And by using this dataset, I want to create an email alert that different BI reports have  failed to refresh and thus, would require  refreshing to different users. So, I would like to create a condition in the alert that it would iterate over the records in the dataset mentioned above, and if it finds a record containing birefreshstatus as Failed, then it would send a mail to the users that this report has failed and it needs to be refreshed

I tried to load the dataset in metric insights but the problem is that only column headers are visible and rest of the records are empty. And I cannot connect this dataset to alerts in order to create condition and send email alerts to users respectively.